# Wicket link - is adding a label necessary to set the text?

Tags: hyperlink, label, wicket

Currently, I do this:

```
<li><a wicket:id="link" href="#"><span wicket:id="name">jawa01</span></a></li>
```

and

```
item.add( new BookmarkablePageLink("link", ResourcePage.class)
   .setParameter("name", item.getModelObject().getName())
   .add( new Label("name", item.getModelObject().getName()) )
);
```

I want to do ommit the  element:

```
<li><a wicket:id="link" href="#">...</a></li>
```

How should the java code look?

I expect something like

```
item.add( new BookmarkablePageLinkWithLabel(
   "link", ResourcePage.class, item.getModelObject().getName())
   .setParameter("name", item.getModelObject().getName())
);
```

Thanks, Ondra

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not built into Wicket, with a couple of reasons presented [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/wicket-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg28621.html).

However, you can certainly make you own component out of what you currently do to make your life easier. The constructor would take both the model for the link and the model for the label.